# C Program will not compile

Tags: c, compiler-errors

When I try to compile my C program the terminal tells me:

`warning: implicit declaration of function 'strcopy' is
      invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]strcopy("test","test");`

I have `#include <string.h>` at the top of my code so I am very confused as to why it will not compile. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Even if you fix the wrong function name, `strcpy("test","test");` invokes undefined bahaviour. You cannot copy any text into a string literal.

Answer (score 6):

Well it says clearly what is the problem. You need to use the function `strcpy` there is nothing called `strcopy` in standard library - and the corresponding implicit declaration considered by compiler is invalid - it complained. Actually C99 doesn't allow implicit declaration - it showed error that's why.

Other options is to declrare the function `strcopy` and then define it before you use it.

Also another thing is how you use `strcpy` - You have passed as both parameter the string literals modifying which is undefined behavior. Not sure what purpose it will serve, given the fact that in general we copy string pointed by `dest` to `src` in `strcpy`. (`src` is the second parameter, `dest` is the first one).

Comment: So what would be the fix?

Comment: @dmeluban.: Use `strcpy` with proper parameters ...`man strcpy` would help.

Comment: @dmeluban.: Other option is also mentioned in answer...choose whichever suits you

Comment: @dmeluban The fix would be to start with reading the chapters about arrays and pointers in your C book, before moving on to strings.

Answer (score 0):

you have typo in your code :
use strcpy instead of strcopy as strcpy is what string library provide.